# How to say $x=f(y)$ is similar to $y=g(x)$?

Tags: functions

I am writing a statement for a model that:

The relationship between two independent variables $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$, a linear model that accounts for errors in from both $x-$ and the $y-$ axis must be defined, such that the model satisfies both $V_1(V_2)$ and $V_2(V_1)$ relationships.

Here, I am using [Deming regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression) where it considers errors from both axes, instead of only in $y-$ axis in OLS.

My intention is to so that it does not matter which variable will be the dependent or predictor variables.

In this case, is $V_1(V_2)$ and $V_2(V_1)$  correct? or is there's another way e.g. $ f(x, y) = f(y, x)$ ?

Comment: It's hard to make sense of your second paragraph. Are $V_i$ variables or functions? What is a relationship "$V_i(V_j)$?

Comment: Also, the current title implies $f = \text{id}$, $g = \text{id}$, $x=y$

Comment: i am writing a total least square regression equation. i just want to say that x can be a function of y, or y as a function of x, it does not matter.

Comment: I'd say each of those statements is an altogether different model. I don't understand how it cannot matter.

Comment: my intention was to say the error is accounted from both directions instead of only in y from OLS...

Comment: I think it would help if you carefully wrote down your assumptions and your model. Do you mean that your independent variable has noise in it as well? Then [this might be of interest](https://web.stanford.edu/class/polisci100a/regress5.pdf)

Comment: no, i am doing orthogonal regression, and i do not want to assume one variable is a function of the other

Comment: I just suggested *noise* not dependency. You say however _"i just want to say that x can be a function of y, or y as a function of x, it does not matter"_. Please carefully write down what you want in the question.

Comment: i have edited the question to see if it makes sense

Comment: Ok, it makes more sense now. In my opinion, you need to do model selection. Either $X$ depends on $Y$ or the other way around. It cannot be both simultaneously and only one choice will be the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

You are given a set of data points $(x_k,y_k)_{1\leq k\leq N}$ belonging to two interdependent variables $V_1$, $V_2$. These data points have errors in both entries. Since they are lying approximatively on a line you are modeling the interdependence of the variables $V_1$ and $V_2$ by a linear equation of the form $$aV_1+b V_2=c\tag{1}$$
with parameters $a$, $b$, $c$ to be determined from the data points in such a way that a certain "total squared deviation" becomes minimal. (In reality there are only two parameters.) This is what Deming regression does for you. After you have found the optimal $a$, $b$, $c$ you can solve $(1)$ for either of the two variables $V_1$, $V_2$, unless $a=0$ or $b=0$:
$$V_1={1\over a}(c-bV_2)\>,\qquad V_2={1\over b}(c-aV_1)\ .$$

Comment: Many thanks for making this clear for me. So it is correct to use Deming regression here because I assume the two variables are independent of one another (or should it be interdependent?)? Therefore, in this case, I have to consider the errors in both entries. 

Because in OLS, one of the variables is dependent on the predictor variable and I do not want to assume this. My apologies for my poor mathematical speaking, I am still learning

Comment: +1 Now it makes sense for me too :)